# Using a data generator for HDF5 file in Python and Keras

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, large-data

I am having trouble writing a data_generator for using with fit_generator in Keras. I have an HDF5 file with 4-dimensional numpy arrays (3-D data, with an extra single dimension from processing) stored as separate datasets.

Each data-set is of the form (xxx, 512, 512, 1) where xxx is the number of slices in that particular dataset. I have a large amount of data (500 3-D images, each with ~300 slices, total ~50 GB, much larger than the RAM I have).

When I run my code, it shows

> Epoch 1/250

and then the ram starts filling up and it gives a memory error. How do I go about writing a data_generator for this? What other methods can I look into?

Here is my code:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas
import pickle
import random
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.backend import tf as ktf
import h5py

with open('categs/database.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    a=pickle.load(f)

def generate_data(a, batch_size):
    while True:
        key=random.choice(list(a.keys()))
        # X_train= np.load(key+'.npy')
        with open('categs/'+key+'.pickle', 'rb') as labels,  h5py.File('datafile.hdf5', mode='r') as f:
            X_train= np.asarray(f[key])
            Y_train=pickle.load(labels)
        X_train1=np.zeros((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2],3))
        for i in range(1,X_train.shape[0]-1):
            X_train1[i,:,:,1]=X_train[i,:,:,0]
            X_train1[i,:,:,0]=X_train[i-1, :, :, 0]
            X_train1[i, :, :,2]=X_train[i+1, :, :, 0]
        X_train=X_train1
        X_train1=[]
        Y_train=np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train)
        yield X_train, Y_train

base_model=ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=(512,512,3), pooling=None)
x=base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(7, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(generator=generate_data(a, batch_size=1), steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=250,workers=6)
```

I have also tried reading the data randomly from the disk by saving each 3-D file as a separate numpy array, but the same thing happens.

Comment: Always include the full, complete error message with traceback in your question.